# Tikz B-Tree Bottom Clearance

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

[image]

[image]

I don't know why latex won't let me split tikzpictures. When I use `\\` in between the `\end` and `\begin{tikzpicture}` nothing happens. When I remove the center instruction it works fine. But I want my graphs to be centered so no way I'll remove them.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please don't use screenshots to add code, it makes it hopeless to test  it.

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  with an empty line followed by the desired vertical space, e.g. `\bigskip` or a `\vspace{5mm}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip% or e.g. \vspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ty, I got it :D